# Model Creation in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a new project in MVC4. I need to create some models. I amd in doubt with a basic  understanding of creating models. Where to keep the models? 
1. Inside MVC model?
2. Seperating models into new project?

Which is the best one ?
Thanks

Comment: dbaseman, Pls again Read the question and you know the meaning of best here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small project is mostly personal preference. I would keep things simple and start with a single project and as complexity or number of team members grow separate modules into projects: data access layer, services, models, etc.

Comment: Thanks, My question is why seperating models into seperate project rather than from using default MVC model architecture? Why cant they use the same architecture on complex projects? Is there any demerits on using it?

Comment: It could be useful if you wanted to define a specific set of model objects and reuse them across applications. Also, I could see how it could help organizing/separating tests from other modules.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, the MVC4 default template will have a `Models` folder created for you. That should be a default place for your models.

Comment: Yes Thanks, i know that. But i seen in many projects that the models are placed in seperate projects. Why about that?

Comment: @DON I think the main reason for that is to introduce one more DAL to your MVC project. In that case it may be more convenient to put your models and your data access logic together in a separate project.